# HTML Date Default Not Showing Value Passed

Tags: html, asp.net

I am using ASP and HTML to display data and enter data into a SQL server.

I am passing a date value when the web page is loaded, but it is defaulting to mm/dd/yyyy. When I look at the live HTML for the web page the value="12/4/2020" is showing.

This works fine in IE, but not on the new Edge.

Any help would be appreciated. I am relatively new to this. [image]

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue. The SQL value I was sending was a smalldatetime. I needed to convert it to a date format.

Thanks!